# svelte in vscode is not formatting

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, svelte

VSCode is not formatting any *.svelte files for me.

If I format this file, nothing happens.
[image]

Env:

I have installed the Svelte for VS Code extension.
I have tried with all my user settings turned off.
All other .vscode settings are working besides svelte formatting.

**.vscode/settings.json**

```
{
"explorer.sortOrder": "filesFirst",
"workbench.editor.labelFormat": "short",
"[svelte]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "svelte.svelte-vscode"
},
"svelte.enable-ts-plugin": true,
"svelte.plugin.svelte.defaultScriptLanguage": "ts",
}
```

**/app/.prettierrc**

```
{
"useTabs": true,
"singleQuote": true,
"trailingComma": "none",
"printWidth": 100,
"plugins": ["prettier-plugin-svelte"],
"pluginSearchDirs": ["."],
"overrides": [{ "files": "*.svelte", "options": { "parser": "svelte" } }]
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `.prettierrc`?

Comment: @H.B. just tried, no difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick here is to remove `"plugins": ["prettier-plugin-svelte"],` from the `.prettierrc`

I found the solution from https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/1820